# How to install jupyter on Google Cloud Virtual Machine?

Tags: google-app-engine, jupyter-notebook

I would like to install `jupyter` on a google gloud VM

I am following this [guideline](https://medium.com/@kn.maragatham09/installing-jupyter-notebook-on-google-cloud-11979e40cd10)

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.shwget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh 

ls
Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh  anaconda3  get-pip.py
```

Then I do

```
export PATH=/home/myname/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Then I get the error

```
jupyter notebook
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I installed jupyter on Google Cloud VM

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install notebook
jupyter --version


jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.9.0
ipykernel        : 5.2.1
jupyter client   : 6.1.3
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.5
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```